# Typescriping keyof object with 1 property issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, deno

So I've created a merge function which takes in an object & a key of another object of objects. The function then returns the merged objects as below.

```
const data = {
    end: 'World'
}

const working = {
    test: 'Worked'
}

const map = {
    data,
    working
}

export type Map = typeof map;

export type Keys = keyof Map;

function merge<A, B extends Keys, C extends Map[B] & A>(input: {
    obj: A;
    append?: B;
}) {

    const append = input.append ? map[input.append] : {};

    return {
        ...input.obj,
        ...append
    } as C
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine when the `map` object has > 1 property. aka

```
const initial = {
    start: 'Hello'
}

const a = merge({
    obj: initial,
    append: 'data'
);

const b = merge({
    obj: initial
});

// Available as expected
console.log(a.end);

// Errors as expected
console.log(b.end);
```

However if I change the `map` object to only have 1 property like so

```
const map = {
    data
}
```

Then this occurs

```
const a = merge({
    obj: initial,
    append: 'data'
);

const b = merge({
    obj: initial
});

// Available as expected
console.log(a.end);

// Available but outputs undefined
console.log(b.end);
```

I kind of understand what is going on. When the `map` object only has 1 property, the generic is defaulting to that key so TypeScript believes the object is merged when it isn't.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: It is returning `undefined` because you have not appended anything when `input.append` is `undefined`

Comment: That's not it, `map[input.append]` can never be undefined because the passed type *has* to be a keyof `map`. So if `input.append` isn't undefined then it is definitely a `keyof map`, otherwise append is an empty object. I've found a solution and will be posting it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
export type Map = typeof map;

export type Keys = keyof Map;

function merge<A, B extends C extends keyof Map ? A & Map[C] : A, C extends undefined | keyof Map = undefined>(input: {
    obj: A;
    append?: C;
}) {

    const append = input.append ? map[input.append as keyof Map] : {};

    return {
        ...input.obj,
        ...append
    } as B
}

const data = {
    end: 'World'
}

const map = {
    data
}

// Testing

const start = {
    hello: 'World'
}

const a = merge({
    obj: start
});

// Outputs as expected
console.log(`${a.hello} World`);

// Errors as expected
console.log(`${a.hello} ${a.end}`);

const b = merge({
    obj: start,
    append: 'data'
})

// Outputs as expected
console.log(`${b.hello} ${b.end}`);
```

So this is how I've gotten it working.

Basically `C` extends `undefined | keyof Map` and has a default type of `undefined` so by default the returned type is `A & undefined`. When a value which *must be* `keyof Map` is passed as the append then `C` becomes that type and thus the returned type is `Map[C] & A`